# What does this snmp v1 ID mean

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

We seeing two Dell DRAC started reporting following warnings

`snmp trap server3.5.2.2.4331`

and I have no idea what does it mean, searched that OID and only found this http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.181.2.3.5.3.2.2

anyone has any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All companies that set up a privately maintained MIB (usually called an "enterprise" MIB) are assigned a MIB designation number. The Dell enterprise MIB assignment number from IANA is 1.3.6.1.4.1.674 (not 1.3.6.1.4.1.181), and looking up the DRAC SNMP traps available on this MIB from http://www.oidview.com/mibs/674/IDRAC-MIB-SMIv2.html shows the trap message 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.3.2.2.0.4331 which means "alertStorageControllerInformation". If there is any message in the output of the SNMP trap, it should point you to the specific fault condition.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.25

> X.25 is an ITU-T standard protocol suite for packet switched wide area network (WAN) communication. An X.25 WAN consists of packet-switching exchange (PSE) nodes as the networking hardware, and leased lines, plain old telephone service connections or ISDN connections as physical links. X.25 is a family of protocols that was popular during the 1980s with telecommunications companies and in financial transaction systems such as automated teller machines. X.25 was originally defined by the International Telegraph and Telephone Consultative Committee (CCITT, now ITU-T) in a series of drafts and finalized in a publication known as The Orange Book in 1976.
>
> While X.25 has, to a large extent, been replaced by less complex protocols, especially the Internet protocol (IP), the service is still used and available in niche and legacy applications.

And what I would take that to mean is that the DRAC is seeing changes to X.25 routing being supported on one or more of your devices on your network.  Whether it's intentional, or just something that someone forgot to turn off, is something you'll need to hunt down.